# Check Bandwidth utilization of specific application or process in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, network-adapter, bandwidth

I want to know is there any ***command-line*** tool (*windows built-in or 3rd party*), that can be used to check bandwidth utilization of a particular process or executable?

For example, i want to check the utilization of a particular program that i am developing over a period of time or may be i just want to detect when it starts utilizing bandwidth over a certain cut off limit that i define.

Reason why i need this, is because i use 3rd party libraries when are dependent on some online resources and i want to enable some functionality that can take appropriate action depending upon certain bandwidth usage if it is exceeding the required limit.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason why it has to be a "command-line tool"?

[NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/) can do what you want, but is managed through a small GUI. It's available in free, cheap and a more expensive edition.

I just don't see anything in your specific requirements that says this couldn't be handled by a GUI program.

Comment: Command-Line because i want to handle everything through software and not through human iteration. if there are command line option, i can invoke external process and run those commands and read the output over output/error stream. with a GUI, you are very limited to the scale of an end user only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure whether there exists a program for this, but you could consider running your program in a virtual machine such that you can use any general network monitoring tool rather than an application specific monitoring tool.

Comment: Interesting, yes that would at least give me a rough idea of utilization, but i won't be able to take action programatically under certain bandwidth utilization.