# Windows Command line way to get network usage of a process

Tags: windows, command-line, network-monitoring

I would like to get the network usage (in bytes or KB) of a specified process through the Windows command line (I'm using Windows 7).  Also if its possible to get a list of all running processes with their associated network usage would be great.

Process Name | Network Usage

I have tried around using typeperf and wmic with no success.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://superuser.com/q/388705/179425)

Comment: What's the reason for it to be command line?

Comment: I need it to be command line because I would like to run automated scripts to monitor network usage.

Comment: You may take a look at tshark mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171336/how-do-i-monitor-network-traffic-on-windows-from-the-command-line